# Why mongodb includes the value outside the range while querying with gt and lt?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch some data within the range using gt and lt filter in mongodb but it's behaving strangely and I don't understand why it's containing the data below the range. Is it because the field is string? Also, If I am putting some random large value for lt like 50000 and gt as 1, it should return all the fields, but it's only returning some records. I am new to mongodb but it should be like other databases. And I am unable to find where I am going wrong.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's because the field "price" is string. And string is compared using dictionary order. In this [document](https://javascript.info/comparison), we can find how string is compared.

> The algorithm to compare two strings is simple:
>
> 1. Compare the first character of both strings.
> 2. If the first character from the first string is greater (or less) than the other string’s, then the first string is greater (or less) than the second. We’re
>    done.
> 3. Otherwise, if both strings’ first characters are the same,
>    compare the second characters the same way. Repeat until the end of
>    either string.
> 4. If both strings end at the same length, then they are
>    equal.
> 5. Otherwise, the longer string is greater.

For example, in your result, there is a document with price is "80", which should not be there. Running the algorithm above to compare "120" and "80", we have :

1. Compare the first character of both strings: "1" < "8". So "120" < "80", that's why the document is presented in the result. (you can run the algorithm to find out that "80" < "800")

I suggest, if possible, you should store price as "Number" type in MongoDB. Then you will be able to use number comparision like you wish.